# How do I 'extract' text from ID?

Tags: android-espresso, gettext

In my test,

I check the text in the header for each page that I land.

I can match the text to “Sign In” (in `R.id.toolbar_text`) for example and see if it pass or fail. But, I would like to know if it failed, what is the text that I have in `R.id.toolbar_text` object.

Is the option `getText()` available in Espresso Android?

How do I 'extract' text from ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an equivalent implementation in Java for getText():

```
public static String getText(final Matcher<View> matcher) {
        try {
            final String[] stringHolder = {null};
            onView(matcher).perform(new ViewAction() {
                @Override
                public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
                    return isAssignableFrom(TextView.class);
                }

                @Override
                public String getDescription() {
                    return "get text";
                }

                @Override
                public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                    stringHolder[0] = tv.getText().toString();
                }
            });
            if (stringHolder[0] == null || stringHolder[0] == "") {
                fail("no text found");
            }
            return stringHolder[0];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail("null found");
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: how is this used?  I'm getting a bunch of "null found".

Answer (score 2):

Try this (kotlin example):

```
val toolbar: ViewInteraction = onView(withId(R.id.toolbar_text))

fun getText(viewInteraction: ViewInteraction): String? {
    val stringHolder = arrayOf<String?>(null)
    viewInteraction.perform(object : ViewAction {
        override fun getConstraints() = isAssignableFrom(TextView::class.java)

        override fun getDescription() = "Get text from View: ${stringHolder[0]}"

        override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View) {
            val tv = view as TextView
            stringHolder[0] = tv.text.toString()
        }
    })
    return stringHolder[0]
}

val text = getText(toolbar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing java version, to use it, simply as below

```
val text = getText(withId(R.id.textViewLastPrice))
```

Comment: This is a comment on [@mark w's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48711303/3025856)—or, more precisely, to [@Zach Folwick's question posted in its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688805/how-do-i-extract-text-from-id/74555794#comment107642892_48711303). It should not be posted as a new answer, since it doesn't answer the original question.